# Can I have Hibernate create an object through factory method?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, factory

Is there a way to map a factory method in Hibernate (as opposed to having Hibernate call a default constructor and reflectively set properties or fields)?

And if it can't be mapped, does Hibernate provide a hook for custom object creation on a class by class basis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is doable using either:

- a custom [`EntityPersister`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister.html) implementation (that you can [register for a particular entity during Hibernate initialization using a custom `Configuration`](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GROM-mapping-and-EntityPersister-tp2134133p2134326.html)) ~or~
- a custom [`Interceptor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) implementing the [`Interceptor.instantiate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#instantiate%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.EntityMode,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method

I think the Interceptor approach is easier. Here is the javadoc of the [`Interceptor.instantiate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#instantiate%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.EntityMode,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

```
/**
 * Instantiate the entity class. Return <tt>null</tt> to indicate that Hibernate should use
 * the default constructor of the class. The identifier property of the returned instance
 * should be initialized with the given identifier.
 *
 * @param entityName the name of the entity
 * @param entityMode The type of entity instance to be returned.
 * @param id the identifier of the new instance
 * @return an instance of the class, or <tt>null</tt> to choose default behaviour
 */
public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id) throws CallbackException;
```

Comment: None of these solutions address the "reflectively set properties or fields" part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

[Take a look](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping-types.html#mapping-types-custom) at [UserType](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). You'd need to call your factory in nullSafeGet() and populate all the fields yourself though. Reverse work is done in nullSafeSet().

Answer (score 2):

> And if it can't be mapped, does
>   Hibernate provide a hook for custom
>   object creation on a class by class
>   basis?

Check out entity listeners. These add just the annotations that will help you out. Think @PrePersist or @PostLoad.

Answer (score 0):

See [Hibernate and Spring transactions - using private constructors/static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336578/hibernate-and-spring-transactions-using-private-constructors-static-factory-met), but not a solution for avoiding the "reflectively set properties or fields" part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I exactly understood what you're asking for, but I think that a solution is described here (see solution 4 - Hibernate interceptor, method onLoad): "Domain Driven Design with Spring and Hibernate" http://www.jblewitt.com/blog/?p=129

Comment: No, onLoad won't allow to change the way Hibernate instantiates entities, which is what the question is about.

Comment: I thought that the question was asking how to populate those objects too, and as far as I can see, Interceptor.instantiate doesn't get any parameter values, only the class name and the object id