# What exactly does mappedby in hibernate mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I tried the documentation but I've got nothing. I tried searching for it on google and stackoverflow but there is still no help. I've got a singleton class and this class has a onetomany relationship to another class. Here's my code.

```
@Entity
public class HomeLibrary extends BaseModelObject {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homeLibrary", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    private static HomeLibrary sharedHomeLibrary = new HomeLibrary();

    public static HomeLibrary getSharedHomeLibrary() {
        return sharedHomeLibrary;
    }

    public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Collection<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    private HomeLibrary() {
    }
}
```

And I got an error in testing. It seems that the table cannot be built.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [HibernateApplicationContext-aop.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on edu.fudan.ss.persistence.hibernate.Book.homeLibrary references an unknown entity: edu.fudan.ss.persistence.hibernate.HomeLibrary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate needs your default constructor to be present in order to create entity, since your constructor is hidden it cannot create your `HomeEntity`.

Either constructor should be public or package visibility, hibernate should be be able to use setAccessible(true) // Note I havent tried package visibility option.

Hibernate and in general framework who create entity uses `Class<T>.newInstance()` via reflection.

mappedBy means that mapping is done by the Owning side, the dependent need not define the mapping.

So in your case you will place mappedBy in `Book` if you are defining mapping in `HomeLibrary`or vice versa.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953800/can-i-have-hibernate-create-an-object-through-factory-method/4092389#4092389) on SO speaks about creating objects via Factory method, you can use that to have your singleton object.

Comment: So no way to store a singleton?