# Generating ID of parent in parent-child persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got a one-to-many parent-child relationship, and I want to persist the entire thing only once. The problem I'm having is that the child has the ID of the parent in it, but at the time of persistence, it's not able to get that ID since it's generated. Here's the setup I've got so far:

```
public class Parent
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "parent-id-gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "parent-id-gen", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long ID;

    // some other fields

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "child-id-gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "child-id-gen", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long ID;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private long parentID;

    // some other fields
}
```

The database (PostgreSQL) looks like this, if it matters:

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  ... other fields,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  parent_id integer NOT NULL,
  ... other fields,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (parent_id, ... other fields)
);
```

I want to only do a single `org.hibernate.Session.saveOrUpdate(parentObject)`, but it's failing my unique key on the child table because the parentID is being set to 0 all the time, rather than the generated ID from the parent.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm thinking Hibernate inserts first, then updates the child with the parent ID so there's no way to do this as the database is currently defined. I'll probably have to remove the unique key as a result, which is unfortunate... if there's a way around that, let me know!

Edit: Added DB info since it's probably pertinent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Hibernate is that your model classes are abstracted from identification stuff between relations. Meaning `private long parentID` could be changed to `private Parent parent`. This will let hibernate know how to control it, and if you need parent's Id, you can do something like `child.getParent().getId()`

Comment: Two things concern me about such an approach, though: (1) how does Jackson handle such a circular relationship when serializing to JSON? and (2) how to define the `@OneToMany` relationship if there's no possible `@JoinColumn`? Is Hibernate smart enough to know the `Child` object has a reference to `Parent`, so there's no need to define a `@JoinColumn` at all? Sounds like I probably need to learn about how JPA is "supposed" to be used...

Comment: Take a look into [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) you can use the mappedBy annotation attribute to define that Child is the owner of this relationship. [this issue could help understand more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10827044/1001027)

Comment: I dumped the `@JoinColumn` and added `mappedBy` to the `@OneToMany` annotation, then had to add a `@OneToOne` annotation to the child. Interestingly, Hibernate's smart enough to expect the `parent_id` column in the child table. However, I haven't been able to get it to actually populate the column (I had to make it nullable in the DB). I suppose that's a different issue entirely.